# WearableListView : add elements 1 by 1

Tags: android, wear-os

After looking at the docs (https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/lists.html), I noticed that you need to give to the adapter an array of strings. Is there a way to use an arrayList so that I can dynamically add items on an occured event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WearableListView extends RecyclerView so all the usual things apply here as well; you can add data and then inform the adapter that the data set has changed by calling notifyDataSetChanged(); there is no magic involved in managing data here.